# What number should come next?

Tags: number-sequence

> 1  3  10  12  14  21 ◇

Identify ◇

Comment: possibly in OEIS:
16- https://oeis.org/A283770
11 - https://oeis.org/A004515

Comment: one more number added

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The next number is

> 23

Reason:

> the numbers are base 5, i.e in decimal they are 1,3,5,7,9,11. The next is 13 in decimal, which is 23 in base 5.

Answer (score 1):

The next number in the sequence is

> 23

Reason:

> Every third number in the sequence is the previous number plus $7$ and all rest are previous number plus $2$. 
>  So the number next in sequence is $21+2=23$.

Answer (score 0):

What about

> 23?

Reasoning:

> The difference between consecutive numbers in the series is 2-7-2-2-7; the next difference is probably 2. So the answer is 21+2=23.

Comment: please notify that before one more number added, it's 2-7-2-2 with your reasoning

Answer (score 0):

> After 21 the digit comes after is 23 because after every odd number add 7 and after every even number only 2 number add. on this case when appear number 1 then comes next is 3.

Comment: But 1 is an odd number